# Dropdown Menu is not working properly

Tags: php, javascript

I used dropdown menu in our site its worked in all browser but in IE6 it's not working properly. so tell me solution. this site is in wordpress.

Thanks
Abhay

Comment: show us some code or provide a lik to your site - how should anyone know whats the problem without this?

Comment: More information required, your question is vague and you will receive no help as it stands.

Comment: How in the world we can determine what drop dowm menu you are using? You should share your code/links.

Comment: "It's not working" is no more use than ringing a garage and saying "My car doesn't go". What do you expect, and what happens that is different?

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use IE6 to view the site.**

That's all I can say with the little information you've provided...

If you want a fix for IE6 you are going to have to show some code, example, etc.

Comment: link for site using themes http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/DeepFocus/ hover the mouse at portfolio menu then drop the box of sub menus

Answer (score 0):

What Thomas said. Big sites like Youtube and Facebook stopped supporting IE6, you should too.